# SOLVED: New to Linux, Trying to install Libre Office

Tags: libreoffice

I'm completely new to Linux OS and have managed to install Elementary on to a netbook, but I'm a bit lost as to how to install Libre Office.

Note that I do not, and will not, be using internet access on the netbook I'm using for this.

However, since much of the info refers to the Downloads directory, I have transferred the latest version of LibreOffice to there, and extracted the files, which are in a DEB folder.

I can get so far as the Terminal being pointe dto the Download directory as follows

'name@name-TOSHIBA-NB305:~Downloads/LibreOffice_6.0.2.1_Linux_x86-64_deb$

From here I have tried 'sudo dpkg -i *.deb'

and am met with the error message as follows:

dpkg: error processing archive *.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Libre office should be in the Elementary App Center.

In case it is not, from the terminal:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update

This will add the repository in your package manager and update it. 
and after:
sudo apt-get install libreoffice

Comment: Thanks Vincenzo. It is not in the App Centre

And when I try to run 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa sudo apt-get update', the response is 'command not found'

FYI the OS version is elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20180214

Comment: sorry, my mistake: first " sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa "

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I didn't want to connect online, but ended up doing so out of desperation, and have now installed LibreOffice.